# anchor.worksace returns empty object {}

Tags: anchor

Having issues with anchor.workspace. Ran anchor build & anchor deploy and there is `target/types/<programname>.ts` at root. Also, anchor.toml is configured properly.

Initially, anchor.workspace worked, but after running anchor build one mre time, it started returning empty object.

Answer (score 2):

after your running "anchor build", anchor will be regerating your idl.json i think, so object "metadata" on your idl.json missing, after build, when you run "anchor deploy", object "metadata.address" will be generate again on your idl.json.
so metadata.address will be show on idl.json after you run "anchor deploy".

Answer (score 0):

In target/idl/program_name.json,

```
"metadata": {
   "address": "...."
}
```

was missing